# File input c++ where lines change

Tags: c++

I need to create a basic calculator that reads from a text file. the file is formatted as follows:

```
2
add 5 3
sub_prev 1
1 
mul 4 5
```

The 2 represents the number of operations, and obviously add means 5 + 6, and the calculator keeps the previous result, so that you can +-*/  it. So that means there are 2 operations: add 5 + 3, then subtract 1 from the previous result. ETC.

I have the file opening fine, but can't figure out how to get it to read correctly.
Ideally, it would read the first integer, enter a loop that reads the correct following number of lines,  and performs the operations. After the for loop completes for the first number of operations, it still be in the file reading while loop, but would re-enter the for loop and read and calculate more operations.

sample code

```
while(myfile) // while reading the file
{
    int PR = 0; //initialize the previous result as 0
    myfile >> no; // grabbing the number of operations
    cout << no << endl; // testing to see if it got it correct

    for ( int i = 1; i <= no; i++) // for the number of operations
    {
        myfile >> no >> op >> x >> y; // read the lines
        if (op == "add") //there would be an if for each operation
        {
            PR = x + y;
        }
    }

    myfile >> no >> op >> x >> y;
}
```

the problem is that it never wants to enter the for loop, it read that the no (number of operations is 2, but it continued through the while loop rather than going into the for loop

** updated code **

```
 while(myfile) // while reading the file
{
    int PR = 0; //initialize the previous result as 0
    myfile >> no; // grabbing the number of operations


    for ( int i = 1; i <= no; i++) // for the number of operations
    {
    myfile >> op;
    if (op == "add") 
    {
     myfile >> x  >> y;
     PR = x + y;
    }      

    if (op == "sub_prev")
    {
        myfile >> x;
        PR = PR - x;
    }  

    if (op == "mul")
    {
        myfile >> x >> y;
        PR = x * y;
        //cout << x << y << PR << endl; //testing mul operation 
    }

    }

    cout << "The result of operation " << " is " << PR << endl;


}
```

it calculates correctly, but outputs wrong:

```
Enter file name: newfile.txt
The result of operation  is 7
The result of operation  is 20
The result of operation  is 20

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

Comment: Any code we can pore over so that we know exactly what you're doing?  Show us what you have so far.

Comment: How do you know it didnt entered the for? how do you check it? I dont know the >> behavior for string, so I would probably have used fscanf.

Comment: I had put a cout statement in the for loop, and it didn't output anything

Comment: [BAM](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cef7cbfa4e1c9e4b02e17bbb9f842547-ea1f0be98f85f91553dec52369656c59) (Yes I deliberately made it complex so if this is homework you can't cheat from my code)

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying `no` here

```
myfile >> no >> op >> x >> y;
```

You shouldn't do that. I would suggest something like the following as a body of the for loop:

```
std::string operation;
myfile >> operation;
if (operation == "add") {
   int a, b;
   myfile >> a  >> b;
   PR = x + y;
} else if (operation == "sub_prev") {
   int value;
   myfile >> value;
   // do something
} else {
   // for other operations if added in future
}
```

Comment: Alright, I think that's the track I need to be going. Basically how to handle lines that have 2 vars (add,etc.) vs 1 (add_prev,sub_prev,etc)

Comment: So my program is now calculating the values correctly for the file (7 and 20), but the loop runs twice for the second file input, even though it should only run once. Outputting the number of operations proves that the value no is updated to one, but the for loop still executes twice.

Comment: @johnsmith, replace `while(myfile)` with `while(true)` but add `if (myfail.fail()) break;` after `myfile >> no;`